# How to properly incorporate applets on HTML page?

Tags: java, html, applet, tags

I have been trying to incorporate my simple Java applet on a HTML page, but I haven't found any luck getting it to work. I have done some research on the matter and I have found some contradictory results.

My understanding is the tags `<applet></applet>` have been deprecated. I went to one site and I read that I needed to use the `<embed></embed>` tag. Then I went to another site and read that I needed `<object></object>` tags. Problem is I have used both of the tags `<embed>` and `<object>`, but I haven't succeed in incorporating my applet on my HTML page.

I am using the Eclipse Juno IDE for the java applet and Notepad++ for the HTML page.

```
<embed width = "60" height = "60" type = "application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0" code = "SimpleApplet.class" > </embed>
```

---

```
<object width = "60" height = "60" classid = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"  >
<PARAM name="code" value="SimpleApplet.class">
 </object>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).  It will use whatever tag is most appropriate for that version of that browser.

Comment: I was hoping you would answer that, with this ;)